# Alternative to a String List to avoid memory problems

Tags: c#, list

So, I'm programming a little word game for a project (with different kinds of didactic games) which basically shuffles the word and the user has to guess it.
Easy so far, but then the same word can't come up more than 1 time so I was using a list to save the used words until I find out the memory problem.
Is there any other way to do it?

My code is this one:

```
String mixed = "";
while (mixed == "" || mixed == word) 
{
    mixed = Shuffle(word);
}
for (int i = 0; i < MainWords.used.Count; i++)
{
    if (word != MainWords.used[i])
    {
        MainWords.used.Add(word);
        palavraigual = false;
    }
}
```

After 12~15 words the program will run into a out of memory exception. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I *very* much doubt that your `OutOfMemoryException` is caused by a list of 12-15 strings (unless your words are millions of letters in length). I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: 12~15 words?  That seems like a really small amount. I'm guessing the problem is something else.

Comment: Going to try and check if it's any specific word.

Comment: 12-15 words gave you an out of memory exception! No way, you must be doing some recursion somewhere, or something else. No modern system will run out of memory because of 15 strings.

Comment: Reading the code, it looks like for every time through the loop, you add the word (n-1) times.

Comment: Your `for` loop contains a bug that causes it to add the same word a very large numer of times to the list, causing the list to grow very fast. You should be able to find the bug easily using the techniques described here: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Oh, I see, I was playing the code around (had a bug) and forgot to stop the cycle after finding the word, going to try out now. Thanks!

Comment: Rather than adding used words to a "used" list, why don't you just remove them from the original list as you use them?

Comment: Matt - I'm using a remote database.

Comment: @user3542380 The problem isn't that you don't stop the cycle, the problem is that you add the word *every time* it doesn't match the word in your list, so if you have 500 words in the list, the new word will be added at least 499 times. Then the next 998 times, then the next ~2000 times, then ~4000 times and so on... You need to add it *once*, *after* the loop if it wasn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be more efficient than a for-loop.  This also prevents you from accidentally making the mistake you did.

```
String mixed = "";
while (mixed == "" || mixed == word) 
{
    mixed = Shuffle(word);
}
if (!MainWord.used.Contains(word))
{
    MainWord.used.Add(word);
    palavraigual = false;
}

public static class MainWord
{
    public static HashSet<string> used;
}
```

Instead of the loop, the above utilizes the `Contains` method.  In this case, the `HashSet` provides a constant-time lookup; however, using `Contains` rather than a loop to check existence is still good practice even if you using a List or other standard data structure.

Since the above does no looping, it is difficult to accidentally add the word more than once; however, Sets have another beneficial behavior here.  They cannot not contain duplicates.  If you kept your looping code but changed the data structure to a `HashSet` you would still avoid your OutOfMemory problem.

Comment: Thanks, I got your idea and it works :) I noticed after this how bad my for worked...and I wasn't aware of HashSet.

Comment: +1: Side note: Whenever constructing `HashSet` make sure to pass correct `StringComparison` if you need case insensitive search.